# Need help deploying a RESTful API created with MongoDB Atlas and Express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, mongodb-atlas

I created a RESTful API with Express and MongoDB Atlas and I'm trying to deploy it on Heroku but for some reason it's not working (working on my localhost).

I would like to get some resources or advice to deploy a small RESTful API to then be able to call it from my front-end which is not yet built.

Here is my `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const appJs = require("./app");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000



appJs.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("listening at " + port);
});
```

and my `App.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const jobRoutes = require("../api/routes/jobs");
const userRoutes = require("../api/routes/user");

mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://myname:${
    process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW
  }@cluster0-z4gre.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);

app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});
```

I did all the steps to deploy on Heroku but I got an error message when I go to the domain name.

My restful API is in JSON format and work perfectly in development mode

Here is the error I get when going to the Heroku URL:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>
> ```
> heroku logs --tail
> ```

my logs that fail:

```
2019-05-04T22:13:54.658480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-04T22:13:54.582531+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-04T22:13:54.582551+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptojobs@1.0.0 start /app
2019-05-04T22:13:54.582553+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon ./server/server.js --exec
2019-05-04T22:13:54.582554+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-04T22:13:54.593393+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2019-05-04T22:13:54.598435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-05-04T22:13:54.598644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-05-04T22:13:54.598901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-05-04T22:13:54.599158+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
```

`nodemon` is installed as a `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Heroku [removes `devDependencies` before deploying your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation). If you need something in production, it probably belongs in your `dependencies`, not `devDependencies`.

But you probably shouldn't be using `nodemon` in production anyway. It's a development tool.

Instead, consider changing your `start` script to use `node` instead of `nodemon`, e.g.

```
"start": "node ./server/server.js"
```

You can add a `dev` script to use `nodemon` while you're editing that file if you want. That way you can use `npm run dev` or `yarn dev` on your local machine to keep your old behaviour.