# Cannot connect to my databse addon on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I attempted to use the command Heroku pg:psql to connect to my database addon in heroku but got a response below

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-regular-61345
unrecognized win32 error code: 123could not find a "psql" to execute
unrecognized win32 error code: 123could not find a "psql" to execute
psql: fatal: could not find own program executable
 !    psql exited with code 1
```

After using the heroku logs --tail command i got the following errors

```
sh: 1: nodemon: not found
Process exited with status 127
State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can also see all processes stopping with SIGTERM and the process exiting with status 143

Resolution steps I have taken

1. Verified that the environment variables have the path for installed postgress14 on my PC
2. Added a procfile to the root file in my backend code and spcified "web: node matthewfaceappback/server.js in the file"
3. Changed my set port to a variable port using process.env.PORT || 3000
4. Set all environment variable including my database url(set by default) on config variable in heroku
5. Verified there is a start up script
6. Updated all my packages using "npm update". after doing this i started expereincing the issue of processes stopping with SIGTERM and the process exiting with status 143
7. I moved nodemon from devDependencies to dependencies. nodemon version is 2.0.15
8. In package.json i inputed an engines parameter using the version of node in my case

   {"engines": {
   "node": "14.17.4"
   }}
9. I restarted heroku using "heroku restart"

Below are links to the screenshots of the error

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bdbyi9e99lbxhu/pic1.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/41euniaes5q68c9/pic2.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/50oqzbwmwrqogax/pic3.PNG?dl=0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. And if you _do_ share screenshots, please only use the official image host by pasting into the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

Put nodemon back in the devDependencies and add it as a second node script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node matthewfaceappback/server.js",
  "dev": "nodemon matthewfaceappback/server.js"
},
```

Comment: i attempted what you suggested but the issue still persist. though reference to nodemon in the error is no longer there

below is the error I see

https://www.dropbox.com/s/77d1x1cij2nsy77/error%201.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j564ot3mq2v44ya/error2.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

These two errors are completely unrelated.

### The database connection error

The first issue, which I believe is the one you actually care about at the moment based on the title of the question, indicates that the Heroku CLI can't find a PostgreSQL client on your *local* machine.

[The documentation makes the following recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-windows)

> #### Set up Postgres on Windows
>
> Install Postgres on Windows by using the [Windows installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads).
>
> Remember to update your PATH environment variable to add the `bin` directory of your Postgres installation. The directory is similar to: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<VERSION>\bin`. Commands like `heroku pg:psql` depend on the PATH and do not work if the PATH is incorrect.

If you haven't already installed Postgres locally, do so. (This is a good idea anyway as you should be developing locally and you'll probably need a database.)

Then make sure to [add its `bin/` directory to your `PATH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/354577).

### The Nodemon error

The second issue is because you are trying to use nodemon in production. Heroku strips development dependencies out of Node.js applications after building them, which normally makes sense. Nodemon is a *development* tool, not something that should be used for production hosting.

Depending on the contents of your `package.json`, this might be as simple as changing your `start` script from `nodemon some-script.js` to `node some-script.js`. Alternatively, you can add a `Procfile` with the command you actually want to run on Heroku:

```
web: node some-script.js
```

See also [Need help deploying a RESTful API created with MongoDB Atlas and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55987475/354577)

Comment: the path environment is well set but still having same error connecting to the database on heroku

got the following errors

https://www.dropbox.com/s/77d1x1cij2nsy77/error%201.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j564ot3mq2v44ya/error2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: i also have database locally setup

Comment: @IfeanyiBardi, again, _[please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577)_. And all errors should be edited into your question, not posted as comments.

Comment: And you _still_ have two different, unrelated errors. The solution to the database connection issue remains what I wrote above. Can you run `psql` on the command-line from the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the entry in the system PATH environment variable for the PostgreSQL bin folder does not have double-quotes (")

In 2013, bug #8472 was filed by Luis Gonzalo Constantini Rickel against PostgreSQL 9.2.4 about this psql.exe behavior but the bug has never been addressed at least in Nov 2023:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1VPJrB-00071y-RR%40wrigleys.postgresql.org

You can produce the same problem on Windows with PostgreSQL 15 installed...
Start cmd.exe
Add psql to the path with a command like:

```
    path "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin";%path%
```

Then try to run psql.exe, and you'll get this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>psql -Upostgres
unrecognized win32 error code: 123could not find a "psql" to execute
Password for user postgres:
```

In contrast, this succeeds

```
    path c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin;%path%
```

results in

```
C:\Windows\System32>psql -Upostgres
Password for user postgres:
```